# Cloudflare cache third party resources

Tags: http, cloudflare

Does Cloudflare perform their reverse proxy cache for third party resources?  For instance, let's say my website is "http://www.expensivehost.com" and I want to keep an image at "a href="http://www.cheaphost.com/image123.jpg"".  Do audience requests go through to the third party host normally or does Cloudflare intercept it?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is the dreaded, 'it depends'.

I think you have slightly misunderstood the concept of a CDN, it can only cache content from domains that they are configured (allowed) to.

So if you own, or the owner of, cheaphost.com configures cloudflare then it will cache that content regardless of whether the request came from expensivehost.com or a direct request.

As such, the note at the bottom is just a little bit misleading, they should change it to "Cloudflare can only cache off-site or third-party resources (widgets, etc.) if those third parties sign up with cloudflare and configure cache policies."